# My program doesn't recognize file when in same folder as program

Tags: c, windows, cs50

[image]

I'm really new to programming just started last week, and i have a problem where my c-file doesn't recognize the cs50.h file when it's in the same folder as my program. i have msys2 installed.

I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Please come with more info, like how you are building and the code in the c file

Comment: i attached a photo but i guess it didn't get posted

Answer (score 1):

Using <header_here.h> takes them from some system wide directory (not sure for windows but for linux it is `/usr/include/`
that has these header files.
For the current path use #include "headername_here.h" instead.

```
#include "cs50.h"
```

Comment: Sorta, but the search path is more complex that just `/usr/include`.  It usually includes `/usr/local/include`, for instance, and may well include some other directories.  There are other nuances to the search algorithm too.